# How to get the Type of GenericDeclaration from ParameterizedType using Java Reflection?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, parameterized-types

I want to analysis the declared field variable in class `MyComponent`, and I want to get the GenericDeclartion's type of the field class, not the type it's declared in `MyComponent`. The demo is below.

```
public class SomeConfig<OP extends Operation> {
    private OP operation;

    public SomeConfig(OP op) {
        this.operation = op;
    }
}

public class MyComponent {
    private SomeConfig<?> config;

    public MyComponent(SomeConfig<?> config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}

public class MyAnalysis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class clazz = MyComponent.class;
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f : fields) {
            Type type = f.getGenericType();
            if(type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                 ParameterizedType pType = (ParameterizedType)type;
                 System.out.println(pType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]); // which prints "?" for sure
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The Problem: The printed result is "?" for sure. But all I want is to get the type of `Operation` to be printed instead of "?". Is it achievable?

Answer (score 3):

> But all I want is to get the type of Operation

Generics are erased after compilation, so you could not access to them in this way at runtime.

To achieve your need, you could change the `SomeConfig` constructor in order to pass the class instance of the parameterized type  :

```
public class SomeConfig<OP extends Operation> {
    private OP operation;
    private Class<OP> clazz;

    public SomeConfig(OP op, Class<OP> clazz) {
      this.operation = op;
      this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

Now the `clazz` field may be used to know the class of the type.

Comment: There's also [`TypeToken`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html), specifically [this constructor](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#TypeToken-java.lang.Class-), but `TypeToken` isn't magic and may or may not work for what the OP is doing. `TypeToken` needs 1. a concrete *non-generic* type argument (else `tt.getType()` will not return a `Class`), 2. a subclass, explicit or implicit and 3. the type argument supplied as if to the `extends` clause to the superclass.

Comment: I don't know well Guava. I looked more in detail `TypeToken`. `TypeToken(Class<?> declaringClass)` seems doing the same thing : storing the class instance in `TypeToken` (no magic as you said). If I understand well, it allows to do the same thing but without adding the class parameter to the constructor as the type capture will be done when TypeToken is instantiated in the declaring class : `new TypeToken<OP>(getClass())`....

Comment: ....It seems really a nice solution as it doesn't denature the constructor signature of the generic class. However, adding a specific library (that could not be used for now) and providing an empty anonymous class to capture the type (that may looks surprising when you read the code) is however a trade-off to think about. Anyway thank you for this information. Really useful.